# How good are the data used by nodejs protected?

Tags: node.js, security

My nodejs application is dealing with sensitive data. Those data are never stored in database/file but only stored in the RAM.

If my server got compromised, how hard is it to read those data?

Comment: Same as any other process.

Comment: Root user can read all memory. This is not made any worse or better with nodeJS.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: This is not an offtopic.